# subscribeOn() not taking work off the main thread

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I'm using RxJava2 with Room SQLite. My DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface HeroDao {
    @Insert
    long create(Hero hero);
}
```

And this is how I use it with RxJava2:

```
Observable.just((int) heroDao.create(hero))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(id -> /** do stuff **/);
```

But when I run the app, the error I get in Logcat is `Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`I've tried attaching `.allowMainThreadQueries()` to the database builder and the insert goes through so that confirms the correctness of my observable. It appears LiveData and AsyncTasks are other approaches that I can try, but I'd rather not go there when I've already made serious investments in RxJava2.

So why am I getting that error? Isn't that `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` sufficient to offload work off the main thread? Otherwise how do I accomplish that? It appears there are some subtleties about converting Room queries into observables that I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you used `Observable.just`. This method just wrap the object into `Observable`, so it's created before actual subscription and call `heroDao.create(hero)` on main thread. You should use `Observable.fromCallable()`, or maybe prefer `Single.fromCallable`.
Also you can define method in DAO like `@Insert Single<Int> create(Hero hero);`

There are some links that maybe be helpful:
[Doing queries in Room with RxJava](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)
[7 Pro-tips for Room](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1)

Answer (score 1):

the answer of @Dmitry Ikryanov is correct, but
you can also use `defer()`

```
createQuery().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(intger -> {
                                //do sth with intege
                            Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            },
                            Throwable::printStackTrace
                    );
              }


  public Observable<Integer> createQuery() {
    return Observable.defer(() -> {
        try {
            return Observable.just((Integer) heroDao.create(hero));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Observable.error(e);
        }
    });
}
```